# Trying to build for android and getting this error: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, flutter

I've been building my app on IOS for quite a while and now I'm working on porting it to Andriod. I've used Flutter for the simple idea that I could just complire my IOS code to android, been tweaking my grandle.build, grandle.propriets but i manage to progress untill this point, where i get this error:

I've read that a solution to the issue I'm facing is to add, to grandle.properties android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
but id didn't fix the issue.

can anybody help me get around this?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.AnimationManager found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.AnimationManager$XAnimation found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.AnimationManager$YAnimation found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.AnimationManager$ZoomAnimation found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.CacheManager found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.CacheManager$PagePartComparator found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DragPinchManager found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView$1 found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView$Configurator found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView$ScrollDir found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView$State found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PagesLoader found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PagesLoader$1 found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PagesLoader$GridSize found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PagesLoader$Holder found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PdfFile found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.RenderingHandler found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.RenderingHandler$1 found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.RenderingHandler$2 found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.RenderingHandler$RenderingTask found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.exception.FileNotFoundException found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.exception.PageRenderingException found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.link.DefaultLinkHandler found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.link.LinkHandler found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.Callbacks found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnDrawListener found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnErrorListener found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageErrorListener found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageScrollListener found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnRenderListener found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnTapListener found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.model.LinkTapEvent found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.model.PagePart found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle$1 found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.ScrollHandle found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.AssetSource found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.ByteArraySource found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.DocumentSource found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.FileSource found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.InputStreamSource found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.UriSource found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.ArrayUtils found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.Constants found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.Constants$Cache found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.Constants$Pinch found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.FileUtils found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.FitPolicy found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.MathUtils found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.PageSizeCalculator found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.PageSizeCalculator$1 found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.util.Util found in modules jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.0.0-beta.4-runtime (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4) and jetified-android-pdf-viewer-3.2.0-beta.3-runtime (com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3)
     Duplicate class com.shockwave.pdfium.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-pdfium-android-1.8.2-runtime (com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.8.2) and jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.2-runtime (com.github.mhiew:pdfium-android:1.9.2)
     Duplicate class com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument found in modules jetified-pdfium-android-1.8.2-runtime (com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.8.2) and jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.2-runtime (com.github.mhiew:pdfium-android:1.9.2)
     Duplicate class com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument$Bookmark found in modules jetified-pdfium-android-1.8.2-runtime (com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.8.2) and jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.2-runtime (com.github.mhiew:pdfium-android:1.9.2)
     Duplicate class com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument$Link found in modules jetified-pdfium-android-1.8.2-runtime (com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.8.2) and jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.2-runtime (com.github.mhiew:pdfium-android:1.9.2)
     Duplicate class com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument$Meta found in modules jetified-pdfium-android-1.8.2-runtime (com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.8.2) and jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.2-runtime (com.github.mhiew:pdfium-android:1.9.2)
     Duplicate class com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfPasswordException found in modules jetified-pdfium-android-1.8.2-runtime (com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.8.2) and jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.2-runtime (com.github.mhiew:pdfium-android:1.9.2)
     Duplicate class com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore found in modules jetified-pdfium-android-1.8.2-runtime (com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.8.2) and jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.2-runtime (com.github.mhiew:pdfium-android:1.9.2)
     Duplicate class com.shockwave.pdfium.util.Size found in modules jetified-pdfium-android-1.8.2-runtime (com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.8.2) and jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.2-runtime (com.github.mhiew:pdfium-android:1.9.2)
     Duplicate class com.shockwave.pdfium.util.SizeF found in modules jetified-pdfium-android-1.8.2-runtime (com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.8.2) and jetified-pdfium-android-1.9.2-runtime (com.github.mhiew:pdfium-android:1.9.2)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I've triend upgrading my android sdk, upgrade the packages that seems to generate the errors. Updated grandle.build and grandle.options

EDIT

here's the android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the android/app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.apprm_nca_android"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.apprm_nca_android"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 34
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

Comment: this might help: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119247

Comment: @Zahra this solution sadly didn't help, I've tried from 1.8.0 to 1.9.0

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle files?

Comment: @tomerpacific sorry for the late response,  I've added both android/build.gradle and android/app/build.gradle. I'm grateful for any time you could find to help me.